# merge two values into one variable

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have two values like 100 and 80 now I wish to store these 2 values in the memory but with in one variable without creating a array or file handling and the thing is retrieving the same values afterwards at another place

Comment: It seems like you have to define some encoding method for your values. For example: `ans = a * 1024 + b`. The receiver shall first compute `(ans / 1024)` and take the integer part to get `a`, and then do `(ans – a * 1024)` to get `b`.

Comment: Thanks sir it really helped I was looking for the same encoding Technique

Answer (score 1):

It could be a strange approach, but this allows having a single varaible actually holding two varaibles.

You can create a `complex` varaible in which the `real` part is the first varaible and the imaginary part is the second variable.

```
a=100;
b=80

c=complex(a,b)
```

You can retrieve the original values using the `real` and `imag` functions

```
a=real(c)
b=imag(c)
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Answer (score 0):

```
a=80;
b=100;
c = [a,b]; % array (row)
c = [a;b]; % array (column)
c.a=a;c.b=b; % struct
c = {a,b}; % cell
```

Several options available.